# Display image from Django database to React JS frontend

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, database

I'm having an issue where the images I upload to Django database aren't displaying into the React JS frontend. I created this model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=False)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=False)
```

I'e serialized it and all that. I then upload that information to the database by going to the /admin url where I can see the database. After that, I make an api call to the database and fetch all the data. Now this is where the issue occurs. I move that data into a `useState([])` and then map that state. The title and description do get displayed on the screen, but the image doesn't. Here is the code where I map the `useState([])`:

```
{projData.map(data => (
     <div key={data.id}>
          <img className="thumbnail" src={data.thumbnail}/>
          <span className="title">{data.title}</span>
          <p className="description">{data.description}</p>
     </div>
))}
```

So like I said, the title and description do successfully get called, but this is the error I get for the image:

> [Error] Failed to load resource: http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/background.png the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (background.png, line 0)

The image does get moved into the images folder. But for some reason, it doesn't display into the actual website. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

you must config your media root,
add this to your settings file

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"assets")
]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_cdn","static_root")
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_cdn","media_root")
```

assets folder is where you store your files locally ,you can skip it cause its not related to your problem.
static root gonna be files like css and java script,and media root are files like images
then add below to your url file

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and dont forget to upload the image again to be stored in media root.
now u have access to your media files in frontend,
see this for more info  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are passing the image, not its location.
Probably you need to, make it `src={data.thumbnail.url}`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I don't get the error anymore, but it still doesn't display the images :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you've changed names of your fields after creation of the model and you should replace old ones - "draft ones" existing eg. in python file with these new one from created API request from your database.